# Como exibir variáveis recebidas em uma JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

Estou trabalhando com servidor *socket*, ele recebe informações de um aplicativo Android, são três informações: mesa, pedido e quantidade. Porém, não consigo mostrar essas informações em um `JFrame`, não faço ideia de como fazer isso, tentei algumas formas, mas todas deu erro de thread. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço desde já!

```
public class Calculadora {

    private static int mesa;
    private static String prato;
    private static String qtd;          

    public Calculadora(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
        //Faz a leitura dos números
        mesa = in.readInt();
        prato = in.readUTF();
        qtd = in.readUTF();
    }

    public int somar() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void enviar(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Mesa: " + mesa + "\nPedido: " + prato + "\nQuantidade: " + qtd);

        out.writeInt(mesa);
        out.writeChars(prato);
        out.writeChars(qtd);
    }

}
```

Essa é a classe responsável por ler e enviar o resultado, mas o meu objetivo não é enviar um resultado e sim mostrar o que foi recebido.

Comment: Você quer exibir automaticamente? Por exemplo, se seu server socket recebe algum pedido, ele já é exibido na tela (o `JFrame`) que você citou?

Comment: Isso, essa é a ideia!

Comment: Você pode informar na pergunta também como está a sua tela até então, o que já tentou fazer? Por que na questão não há nada sobre as suas tentativas na construção da tela.

Comment: A minha tela esta como teste, ela simplesmente esta com 3 label para receber esses valores, é uma tela bem simples mesmo, pois estou tentando fazer funcionar nela, para que eu possa adicionar em um CRUD que eu tenho.

Answer (score 1):

Existem muitas formas de você fazer isto, aparentemente seu problema é de **OO**, organização do seu aplicativo.

Basicamente você precisa que os dados de `mesa`, `prato` e `qtd` estejam disponíveis no objeto da tela a ser atualizada, então você pode organizar seu código de infinitas formas para atender isso.

Irei mostrar um examplo básico disto funcionando, mas você deve organizar sua aplicação da forma que melhor for conveniente para você.

Para a sua tela simples irei considerar que você tenha alguma coisa assim, apenas com labels, como dito por você em um dos comentários na sua questão:

[image: JFrame com Labels]

Gerada por um código parecido com este:

```
public class JFrameSimplesPedido extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2339970233456764439L;

    private final String lblMesaInicial = "Mesa: ";
    private final JLabel lblMesa;

    private final String lblPratoInicial = "Prato: ";
    private final JLabel lblPrato;

    private final String lblQuantidadeInicial = "Quantidade: ";
    private final JLabel lblQuantidade;

    public JFrameSimplesPedido(final String title) {
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        lblMesa = new JLabel(lblMesaInicial);
        contentPane.add(lblMesa);

        lblPrato = new JLabel(lblPratoInicial);
        contentPane.add(lblPrato);

        lblQuantidade = new JLabel(lblQuantidadeInicial);
        contentPane.add(lblQuantidade);
    }

}
```

Para organizar o mínimo possível, encapsulei os atributos em um objeto `SimplesPedido`:

```
public class SimplesPedido {

    private int mesa;
    private String prato;
    private String quantidade;

    // getters e setter

}
```

Vamos agora ver uma forma de atualizar os labels. Na classe `JFrameSimplesPedido` irei disponibilizar um método para atualizá-las, assim:

```
public void updateLabels(final SimplesPedido pedido) {
    lblMesa.setText(lblMesaInicial + pedido.getMesa());
    lblPrato.setText(lblPratoInicial + pedido.getPrato());
    lblQuantidade.setText(lblQuantidadeInicial + pedido.getQuantidade());
}
```

Para gerar novos pedidos irei usar um `Thread`, vamos chamá-lo de `ThreadSimplesPedido`, que chamará o método `updateLabels` da instância de `JFrameSimplesPedido` que ele conhece, para atualizar os labels, algo como isto:

```
public class ThreadSimplesPedido implements Runnable {

    private final JFrameSimplesPedido frame;

    public ThreadSimplesPedido(final JFrameSimplesPedido frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // 'dorme' por 5 segundos e depois gera outro pedido
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            frame.updateLabels(gerarPedido());
        }
    }

    private final Random random = new Random();

    private SimplesPedido gerarPedido() {
        final SimplesPedido pedido = new SimplesPedido();
        pedido.setMesa(random.nextInt(100));
        pedido.setPrato("" + random.nextInt(100));
        pedido.setQuantidade("" + random.nextInt(100));
        return pedido;
    }

}
```

Perceba que eu simplesmente atualizo os labels chamando o método `updateLabels` a cada vez que um novo pedido "chega".

Na classe `JFrameSimplesPedido` irei remover o `main` e criar uma nova classe para iniciar nossa aplicação, algo assim:

```
public class SimplesApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Runnable runner = () -> {
            final JFrameSimplesPedido frame = new JFrameSimplesPedido("Update Simples de Pedidos");
            frame.setVisible(true);

            final ThreadSimplesPedido tPedido = new ThreadSimplesPedido(frame);
            final Thread t = new Thread(tPedido);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
    }

}
```

Ao rodarmos `SimplesApplication`, este é o que iremos observar:

[image: Atualiza Pedidos - JLabels]

Como disse no ínicio, existem diversar formas de fazer isto, uma delas que você pode usar é com [`Observer`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer), um padrão de projetos que pode lhe ajudar, busque como usá-lo. Com ele você pode notificar os observadores, no caso sua tela.

Esta imagem abaixo é uma outra forma de fazer e usei o `Observer` citado e uma tela uma pouco mais elaborada:

[image: Atualiza Pedidos - JTable e Observer]

Fica para servir de inspiração =)

Finalizando e reforçando, você pode projetar seu aplicativo de diversas formas, esta resposta é um *norte* funcional do que você pode fazer.

Comment: Ola bruno, desculpa demora para dar a resposta, fiz o projeto que esta na sua resposta, coloquei a classe que recebe os valores dentro da ThreadSimplesPedido e dentro do metoto gerarPedido eu eu coloquei as variáveis , porem ele não mostra na tela, mostra nulo, como se não tivesse nada dentro das variáveis, fiz um printnl pra ver se realmente nao tinha nada, mas printava os valores recebidos.

Comment: @Brunoleonelnunes cara, se você fez exatamente como o exemplo, não tem como printar `null`. As imagens foram feitas com este exemplo e nelas estão os valores, não `null`. Agora, se está `null`, é porque é outra instância e não a criada em `gerarPedido`. Sugiro revisar seu projeto, infelizmente não há mais a ser feito do que o que está na resposta, já que é um exemplo funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia criar métodos *static* na classe que extende JFrame? Você atualizaria as informações por estes métodos e poderia acessá-los por fora da classe.

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma, porem os valores não passava, sempre recebia nulo.